# Python Dictionay

Tags: python, dictionary

```
a = {'Role1':['G1','G2','G3','H1'],'Role2':['G5','G6','G0'],
'Role3':['G7','G8'],'Role4':['A5','A6','A0'],'Role5':['C5']}
```

this dict I want to convert with new keynames like below taking consideration Role1 key and its corresponding list of values

```
c= {"roles":"Role1","people":[{"ppl":'G1'},{"ppl":'G2'},{"ppl":'G3'},{"ppl":'H1'}]}


c = dict()
for i,j in a.items():
    for k in j:
        c.update({"roles":i})
        c.update({"people":[{"ppl":k}]})
```

this gives me below result with only 1st list value ignoring rest all:
output:

```
c= {"roles":"Role1","people":[{"ppl":'G1'}]}
```

expected output:

```
[{'roles': 'Role1', 'people': [{'ppl': 'G1'}, {'ppl': 'G2'}, {'ppl': 'G3'}, {'ppl': 'H1'}]},
 {'roles': 'Role2', 'people': [{'ppl': 'G5'}, {'ppl': 'G6'}, {'ppl': 'G0'}]},
 {'roles': 'Role3', 'people': [{'ppl': 'G7'}, {'ppl': 'G8'}]},
 {'roles': 'Role4', 'people': [{'ppl': 'A5'}, {'ppl': 'A6'}, {'ppl': 'A0'}]},
 {'roles': 'Role5', 'people': [{'ppl': 'C5'}]}]
```

Comment: ``update()`` **replaces** the existing key-value, not expands it.

Comment: Please provide the complete expected output for clarity

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple, use a nested list/dictionary comprehension, this is the most pythonic:

```
out = [{'roles': role, 'people': [{'ppl': p} for p in ppl]}
       for role, ppl in a.items()]
```

Output:

```
[{'roles': 'Role1',
  'people': [{'ppl': 'G1'}, {'ppl': 'G2'}, {'ppl': 'G3'}, {'ppl': 'H1'}]},
 {'roles': 'Role2', 'people': [{'ppl': 'G5'}, {'ppl': 'G6'}, {'ppl': 'G0'}]},
 {'roles': 'Role3', 'people': [{'ppl': 'G7'}, {'ppl': 'G8'}]},
 {'roles': 'Role4', 'people': [{'ppl': 'A5'}, {'ppl': 'A6'}, {'ppl': 'A0'}]},
 {'roles': 'Role5', 'people': [{'ppl': 'C5'}]}]
```

To restrict it to one role:

```
role = 'Role1'
c = {'roles': role, 'people': [{'ppl': p} for p in a[role]]}
```

Output:

```
{'roles': 'Role1',
 'people': [{'ppl': 'G1'}, {'ppl': 'G2'}, {'ppl': 'G3'}, {'ppl': 'H1'}]}
```

Using your original loop:

```
out = []
for i, j in a.items():
    l = []
    out.append({'roles': i, 'people': l})
    for k in j:
        l.append({'ppl': k})
```

Comment: thank you mozway . this works perfect for my requirement. thank you once again .Was trying to get this output for a long time .

Comment: @GV so the first solution gives the expected output (list of dictionaries)? I'll update the question with it.